# Translate simple code from jQuery to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem. I need to translate from jQuery to JS. It is strange but I need in this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.help-image').each(function() {
    var link = $(this).html();
    $(this).contents().wrap('<a href="#help"></a>');
  });
});
```

Thank you in advance and I hope for an early reply.

Comment: Okay, so do it.

Comment: https://j11y.io/jquery/

Comment: please show current dom

Comment: Variable `link` does not seem to be used...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet will do exactly what you are searching for. But using jQuery is much better imo. Browsers which cannot interprete jQuery correctly should not be used anyway.

```js
(function() {
  let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('help-image')
  for (let element of elements) {
    let oldHtml = element.innerHTML;
    let newHtml = "<a href='#help'>" + oldHtml + "</a>";
    element.innerHTML = newHtml;
  }
})()
```

```html
<div class="help-image">a</div>
<div class="help-image">b</div>
<div class="help-image">c</div>
<div class="help-image">d</div>
```